# wsimport Xauthfile error

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, ssl, wsimport

I am trying to generate the java help classes that I need for a client (a.k.a consumer) for a SSL-protected web service (on Microsoft Biztalk) that is external to our company network. We can access it only over a proxy and we cannot change anything about the Webservice itself.

This is my command provided to the wsimport tool:

```
wsimport -keep -httpproxy:theProxy.net:8080 -s c:\generatedWebService_wsImport\ -p the.java.package.I.want.to.call.it -Xauthfile c:\generatedWebService_wsImport\auth https://meldeservice-test.oekb.at/Meldeservice/WebService_at_oekb_biztalk_MeldeService.asmx?WSDL
```

and *this is the content of my auth file*:

```
https://user:pwd@meldeservice-test.oekb.at:8080/Meldeservice/WebService_at_oekb_biztalk_MeldeService.asmx?WSDL
```

And **this is the error I get**:

> [ERROR] Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https:
>   //meldeservice-test.oekb.at/Meldeservice/WebService_at_oekb_biztalk_MeldeService.asmx?WSDL,
>   "https:
>   //meldeservice-test.oekb.at/Meldeservice/WebService_at_oekb_biztalk_MeldeService.asmx?WSDL"
>   needs authorization, please provide authorization file with read
>   access at C:\Documents and Settings\s6424.metro\auth or use
>   -Xauthfile to give the authorization file and on each line provide authorization information using this format :
>   http[s]://user:password@host:port//

Of course the proxy and credentials are different as in this post. The password contains a special character ! (exclamation mark).

Can someone help me with a working example under similar conditions. I had already searched a lot but couldn't find anything that would have helped me.

Is there somewhere a downloadable source code of the wsimport tool? This would be as the last resort to use.

Answer (score 1):

Try to open https://user:pwd@meldeservice-test.oekb.at:8080/Meldeservice/WebService_at_oekb_biztalk_MeldeService.asmx?WSDL

with your browser and save to local folder. Later you can use a wsimport like this:

**wsimport -keep -s c:\generatedWebService_wsImport\ -p the.java.package.I.want.to.call.it  /home/user/Download/example?WSDL**

Regards,

Comment: IS it necessary to save a local copy of wsdl? Is there no valid way of importing client artifacts directly via wsimport?

Answer (score 1):

in your request, you used

```
https://meldeservice-test.oekb.at/Meldeservice/WebService_at_oekb_biztalk_MeldeService.asmx?WSDL
```

in your auth file, it is

```
meldeservice-test.oekb.at:8080/Meldeservice/WebService_at_oekb_biztalk_MeldeService.asmx?WSDL
```

try removing the port number, change it to

```
https://user:pwd@meldeservice-test.oekb.at/Meldeservice/WebService_at_oekb_biztalk_MeldeService.asmx?WSDL
```