# wsimport with special character and Xauthfile

Tags: web-services, ssl, soapui, wsimport, xauth

I'm facing the same problem that this guy here:

> [wsimport Xauthfile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359877/wsimport-xauthfile-error)

Since he didn't gave a feedback and I'm new here and can't ask him if he solved his problem I'm opening a new question.

I'm using ubuntu and have JDK7 from java oracle installed.

I'm consuming a thirdparty web service. The password (...GT@#ED...) for the webservice have a character that conflicts with de -Xauthfile syntax (http[s]://user:password@host:port//) because of the "@". The dots (...) represents the rest of my password.

Here is the command I'm running:

```
wsimport -p loa -Xauthfile "path_to_auth.txt" https://myWS?wsdl
```

In my auth.txt file I have:

```
https://user:...GT@#ED...@myWS?wsdl
```

In return a get

```
parsing WSDL...    
[ERROR] Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://myWS?wsdl,  
"https://myWS?wsdl" needs authorization, please provide authorization file with
read access at /home/user_name/.metro/auth or use -Xauthfile to give the 
authorization file and on each line provide authorization information using this 
format : http[s]://user:password@host:port//<url-path>
```

I search all over the net, but no success.

When I try to import the WS using SoapUI like in this [tutorial](http://blog.lebrijo.com/jax-ws-ws-client-generating-with-soapui/) I got a

```
[ERROR] sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid 
certification path to requested target
```

and I don't know where to specify the ssl file for SoapUI. I tryed in

> preferences -> SSL Settings

but no lucky.

That's it. I'll apreciate any help.

**EDIT**

OK, so I pass through the authorization, changing the characters using the [HTML URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp), but now I'm getting the following error

```
[ERROR] Server redirected too many  times (20),  "https://ws?wsdl" needs 
authorization, please provide authorization file with read access at /home/user
/.metro/auth or use -Xauthfile to give the authorization file and on each line 
provide authorization information using this format : 
http[s]://user:password@host:port//<url-path>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Apache axis2 instead of wsimport. first this problem happened for me, and I write a bash script and it worked.

```
#!/bin/bash
/axis2-1.7.9/bin/wsdl2java.sh -uri http://username:password@domain/x?wsdl
```

I also use encoding password and username by 'url encoding' such as bellow:

@#%g3E99! -(URL encoding)-> %40%23%25g3E99%21

Answer (score -1):

First create auth.txt file where you need to put the following and save it in C drive:

```
http://username:password@localhost:port/wsdlurl
```

Now run the following command:

```
wsimport -Xauthfile C:\auth.txt -keep http://example.com/test?wsdl
```

This worked for me.